# DropdownList is giving a null value to controller calling model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a student developer in ASP.NET. I have a question which i did not find a solution about it. I can build a form for my controller. i am taking a value from my input objects but i am not taking value from dropdown list to my controller. It gives null value on my controller. Could you help me about  where i made a mistake?

My View Model :

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
    public Country Country;
}
```

My controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = new CountryViewModel()
        {
            CountryList = db.Country.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string timeForCheckedOut,CountryViewModel cvModel)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

my index.cshtml:

```
   @model PenaltyCalculation.Models.ViewModel.CountryViewModel

<form class="" style="margin-top:10%;" action="/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check out date of the Book</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="timeForCheckedOut">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Choose a country</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Country.countryId,new SelectList(Model.CountryList,"countryId","countryName"),new {@class="form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

My Country Model:

```
 public partial class Country
    {
        public int countryId { get; set; }
        public string countryName { get; set; }          
    }
```

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? Also can you post the Country class.

Comment: Country has only two columns,(countryId and countryName). I am using .net framework 4.6.1 in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Make `CountryID` as separate property of Model and bind that to DropDownList. You also have to make `timeForCheckedOut` as property of model

Comment: Open developer tools in your browser (F12), go to the network tab, then click submit on your form. Find the Post request and look at the request body. See what the properties names are that are being sent. Your HttpPost method's properties must match them exactly. Also, I am not sure what you are doing with that CountryViewModel.

Comment: I just want to take a value from dropdownlist and I want to use it in my controller.

Comment: Do you need the value of the countryId and countryName to use in your controller?

Comment: Yes. I want to use them in my Index controller. But ı want to choose them according to value  coming from  dropdowndownlist.

Comment: I do have one totally unrelated question. Why is your Country Class a partial class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1:**

You just need to put the **{ get; set; }** on the end of Country in your CountryViewModel. This will allow you to set the countryId value, but the name will not be set. You will have to look that up from your db if you need that also.

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Option #2**

This is what I would do. Remake your CountryViewModel to actually represent your View's Model.

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeForCheckedOut { get; set; }
}
```

Then update your controller.

```
    // Simulating a db
    private List<Country> Countries;

    public HomeController()
    {
        // Initializing sample data
        Countries = new List<Country>();

        Countries.Add(new Country() { countryId = 1, countryName = "USA" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { countryId = 2, countryName = "England" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { countryId = 3, countryName = "Japan" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { countryId = 4, countryName = "China" });
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // I prefer using the ViewData Dictionary for my selectlists
        ViewData["CountrySelectList"] = new SelectList(Countries, "countryId", "countryName");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CountryViewModel cvModel)
    {
        var country = Countries.First(c => c.countryId == cvModel.CountryId);
        // Do Stuff Like Saving and Updating

        ViewData["CountrySelectList"] = new SelectList(Countries, "countryId", "countryName", cvModel.CountryId);
        return View(cvModel);
    }
```

And Finally update your View

```
@model PenaltyCalculation.Models.ViewModel.CountryViewModel

<form class="" style="margin-top:10%;" action="/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check out date of the Book</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="timeForCheckedOut">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Choose a country</label>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountrySelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's great answer and it is a thing what i am looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountryController : Controller
{
    // GET: Country
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new CountryViewModel()
        {
            CountryList = GetCountries()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CountryViewModel model)
    {
        model.CountryList = GetCountries();
        return View(model);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        return new Country[]
            {
                new Country()
                {
                    CountryID = 1,
                    CountryName = "USA"
                },
                new Country()
                {
                    CountryID = 2,
                    CountryName = "Mexico"
                },
            };
    }
}

public class CountryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeForCheckedOut { get; set; }
}

public partial class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

<form class="" style="margin-top:10%;" action="/Country/Index" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check out date of the Book</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="TimeForCheckedOut">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Choose a country</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "CountryID", "CountryName"), new { @class = "form-control" })        
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

This is working for me

Make sure `CountryID` has getter and setter. Also in C# public property name starts with Capital letter (by convention)

I would also suggest, don't bind `Country` entity directly to view. You may want to create `CountryModel`

Comment: I did it but cvModel is only showing timeForCheckedOut as not null. Another columns are still same null.